# when i try to register by my app i didn't get any respnse

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to save my data to server. can any one help me?

when i am trying to save data through browser it is working fine but when i try it through this code doesn'n give any response??

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "dRegister";
EditText etName, etEmail, etMobile, etPassword, /*etRePassword*/
        etCity;
Button register;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    etMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile);
    etCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCity);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    //etRePassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rePassword);
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
    register.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final String name = etName.getText().toString();
    final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
    final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
    final String city = etCity.getText().toString();
    final String phoneno = etMobile.getText().toString();

    StringRequest registerRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,RegisterRequest.REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response + " Response");
            if(response.equals("SUCCESS")){
                startActivity(new Intent(Register.this,MainActivity.class));
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "You have not Registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error " + error.toString());
            if(error.networkResponse == null){
                if(error.getClass().equals(TimeoutError.class));
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "oops Time out error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders()throws AuthFailureError{
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("name",name);
            headers.put("email",email);
            headers.put("password",password);
            headers.put("city",city);
            headers.put("phoneno",phoneno);
            return headers;
        }
    };
    registerRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(1000 * 15,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    /*Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response + "");
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                if (success) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Registration failed").setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                            .create().show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, email, city, phoneno, password, responseListener){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            //super.getHeaders();
            Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            String credential = "raju@gmail.com:123";
            String auth = "Basic "+ Base64.encodeToString(credential.getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP);
            //headers.put("Content-Type");
            headers.put("Authorization",auth);
            //
            return headers;
        }
    };*/
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);
            registerRequest.setShouldCache(false);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
}
}
```

Here Is my server code....

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/savemobileUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String saveUser(@RequestBody MobileUserModel mobileUser) {

    MobileUserModel user = new MobileUserModel();
    user.setActivationKey(mobileUser.getActivationKey());
    user.setCity(mobileUser.getCity());
    user.setEmail(mobileUser.getEmail());

    user.setImeino(mobileUser.getImeino());

    user.setName(mobileUser.getName());

    user.setPassword(mobileUser.getPassword());

    user.setPhoneno(mobileUser.getPhoneno());

    userrepository.save(user);

    System.out.println("Saved");

    // return "User has been saved Successfully";
    return "SUCCESS";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put following inside your onClick method:

```
switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bRegister:


            // add your registration process code here



            break;
}
```

Comment: i tried but i get com.android.volley.ServerError how to handle this error

Comment: i get E/Volley: [170] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 415 can you help me

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you have given Internet permissions in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your json response format and also the parameter type that you are sending. It may occur due to different reasons, for example, there is an json array in response and you are mapping it just in simple object or the attributes (variable) that you are mapping into it, names are not  exactly similar to json response filed or there can be different multiple reasons.